# Учитывать пробел при поиске.

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте помогите пожалуйста. Есть такой скрипт.

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['q'])) {
  $search_value = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['quick']);
  echo '<div id="search_value">Результат поиска:&nbsp;<b>'.$search_value.'</b></div></div>';
  $query = "SELECT id,avatar,username,family,city,country,sex,birthdateDay,birthdateMonth,birthdateYear from users where username like '%$search_value%' OR family like '%$search_value%' OR country like '%$search_value%' OR city like '%$search_value%' OR sex like '%$search_value%'";
  $run = mysql_query($query);
  while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($run)) {
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($row['username']);
    $family = mysql_real_escape_string($row['family']);
    $country = mysql_real_escape_string($row['country']);
    $city = mysql_real_escape_string($row['city']);
    $avatar = $row['avatar'];
    $id_users = $row['id'];
?>
При вводе например имени или фамилии он ищет, а если пишу имя ставлю пробел и фамилию то не ищет.Помогите пожалуйста как сделать что бы пробел учитывался при поиске.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавь еще одно условие в запрос

```
OR CONCAT(username, ' ', family) LIKE '%$search_value%'
```

Ну и еще одно для обратной комбинации

```
OR CONCAT(family, ' ', username) LIKE '%$search_value%'
```

Comment: @ICE Спасибо вам большое.